# A way to create an interface extending comparator interface that compares current subclass only

Tags: java, generics, interface, java-8

I'd like to define an interface which imposes compare but against its particular type instead of all the parent interface types.

```
public interface MyInterface extends Comparable<MyInterface>
```

so the implemented classes would automatically describe

```
compare(Subclass x)
```

instead of

```
compare(MyInterface)
```

is that possible?

Comment: Then I guess Sublcass would be defined as  Subclass implements MyInterface<Subclass>. Isn't like that? If so a nice last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
interface MyInterface<C extends MyInterface<C>> extends Comparable<C> {

}
```

Which would force implementations to specify their own type, thusly:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass o) {

    }
}
```

But you have to ask yourself, what do you gain from this?

You would have to pass this around as:

```
final MyInterface<MyClass> o = new MyClass();
```

Otherwise it would be a rawtype.

An `interface` abstracts from the implementation of the class so you should be able to pass around a reference to a `MyInterface` and everyone will my able to access the methods defined on `MyInterface` without caring what the implementing class is.

By only allowing comparison between `MyClass` and `MyClass` you completely lose this abstraction. You force any user of `MyInterface` to know the exact implementation as comparing two *different* implementations would result is a `ClassCastException`.

You would never be able to safely compare a `MyInterface` to another `MyInterface` unless they both had the same `C` - In which case you could just compare `C` to `C`...

Comment: That's a good question... the last part. Made me thiink of it seriously. Thanks

Comment: [Practical example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html). Note that you can (and probably should) remove the `? super` part of the type signature.

Answer (score 1):

I reused the idea from Boris with the generics and applied it on an abstract class.

```
interface MyInterface extends Comparable<Object> {
}


public abstract class AbstractCompareDelegator<C extends AbstractCompareDelegator<? super C>> implements MyInterface {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public final int compareTo(final Object o) {
        if (!this.getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }
        return compare(((C) o));
    }

    protected abstract int compare(final C o);
}


public class FullName extends AbstractCompareDelegator<FullName> {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public FullName(final String firstName, final String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    protected int compare(final FullName o) {
        final int firstNameDiff = firstName.compareTo(o.firstName);
        if (firstNameDiff != 0) {
            return firstNameDiff;
        }
        final int lastNameDiff = lastName.compareTo(o.lastName);
        if (lastNameDiff != 0) {
            return lastNameDiff;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("FullName [firstName=%s, lastName=%s]\n", firstName, lastName);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Collection<MyInterface> orderedNames = new TreeSet<MyInterface>();
        // add names unordered
        final MyInterface name1 = new FullName("Luke", "Skywalker");
        orderedNames.add(name1);
        final MyInterface name2 = new FullName("Joe", "Black");
        orderedNames.add(name2);
        final MyInterface name3 = new FullName("Forest", "Gump");
        orderedNames.add(name3);
        final MyInterface name4 = new FullName("John", "Rambo");
        orderedNames.add(name4);
        // was the set ordered?
        System.out.println(orderedNames);
    }
}

Output:
[FullName [firstName=Forest, lastName=Gump]
, FullName [firstName=Joe, lastName=Black]
, FullName [firstName=John, lastName=Rambo]
, FullName [firstName=Luke, lastName=Skywalker]
]
```

- I have applied an abstract class between the concrete class and the interface.
- I did not restrict the genetic type in the interface. I leave it as Object. I do the restriction in the abstract class compareTo()
- I delegate the compareTo() from the abstract class to the concrete subclass compare() to be overridden with the concrete class parameter.
- Now you can use the **MyInterface** to refer to a concrete subclass without any generic mentioned in the reference type.
- You should use the **MyInterface** carefully because references to instances of different classes cannot be compared (it throws ClassCastException as mention already in previous comment)
- You lose the possibility in the concrete class in my example to extend other class because it already extends the technical abstract class. This is not nice.
- You can organize **MyInterface** references to different collections but do not sort them! Ensure before sorting they are instances of the same class.

Comment: So you found a complicated way of throwing away all advantages of Generics…